# C# List data to jqPlot.

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, jqplot

I have two C# lists that contain and x-axis and y-axis points.

```
List<string> xaxis = xAxisData(url);
List<string> yaxis = yAxisData(url);
```

I want to pass points to my jqPlot script chart so that I can plot them.

Below is my code for .aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var x = $('.lclass').html();
        var xaxis = ???;
        var yaxis = ???;

        var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [xaxis], {
            title: x,
            axesDefaults: {
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                rendererOptions: {
                    smooth: false
                }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    label: "Date",
                    numberTicks: 4,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%MM:%DD'
                    },
                    pad: 0
                },
                yaxis: {
                    label: "GB"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two general ways to solve this problem

1. Include the data as part of the rendered ASP.NET page. This is assuming the data will not change while the page is displayed for the user. The exact code to do it depends on technology you use and there is more than one way to do it. E.g. in razor that can be done like this

   @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataAsJson)

   where you put the JSON represneation of your data as a string in your ViewBag.To turn your data to a JSON object, you can use NewtonSoft's library
2. You fetch the data from a RESTful service because you want the data to refresh without needing to refresh the page. Again there is more than one way to do this. One is to implement an ApiController and then in the client side use a AngularJS and $http service to fetch and use the data.